# Calculate normal and plane orientation using 4 3D points

Tags: unity, c#, vector, quaternion, linear-algebra

I have 4 points as `Vector3` in 3D space that shape a plane. How can I calculate the plane normal direction these four points create together, and express it as a `Quaternion`?

[image: Guide Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we'll average together the vertical and horizontal edges of your quad to get two vectors, pointing in the directions of the x and y axes of the transform gizmo in your diagram:

```
var x = C - A + D - B;
var y = C - D + A - B;
```

The z direction is then

```
var z = Vector3.Cross(x, y);
```

We can turn this into a quaternion using:

```
var planeOrientation = Quaternion.LookRotation(z, y);
```